# How to automatically recover from MySQL query error in MySQL replication?

Tags: mysql, database, replication

I am replicating MySQL databases and replication stops whenever there is an error in MySQL query i.e., duplicate entry etc.

How can replication recover from query errors by itself without the skipping the binlogs manually ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In order to skip past things like duplicate entry (error number 1062), you'll need to configure your slave to skip those errors.

In my.cnf:

```
slave-skip-errors = 1062
```

You will need to restart mysql for this change to take effect.

This is a comma delimited configuration, so if you come across more error codes you want to skip past, add them on the end and restart the service.

Comment: is there a way by which MySQL can recover from errors itself and i don't need to restart MySQL

Comment: To my knowledge, sadly no.